# Convert R code to Rcpp - for loop, vector input, vector output

Tags: r, rcpp

I am beginner to Rcpp and C++. If I could see a working example relative to my context it might help me in my journey.

Lets take the following R code:

```
value <-c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,-2.0,0.7,0.4,-10,0.1,0.2,0.4,3.0,0.6,0.7,0.8,-1.2,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.5,2,0.1,0.2)
res <- NULL
while (length(res) < length(value)) {
  if (value[length(res)+1] < -1) {
    res <- c(res, rep(1,5))
  } else {
    res <- c(res, 0)
  }
}
```

with numerical output:

```
> str(res)
 num [1:25] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The code is a for loop, find instances of `< -1` and then append a vector with rep 1,5 times else if not -1 do 0.

Next I wish to send this off to Rcpp:

I am following some examples here:

[Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) and http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com

My conversion attempt is below:

```
cppFunction('double resC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
            double res = 0;
            for(int i = ; i < n; ++i) {
  if (value[i] < -1) { 
  res += c(res, rep(1,5));
  } else {
    res += c(res, 0);
  }         
            return res;
            }')


resC(value)
```

Can C++ append to vectors the same way R can? Its looking like not a straight similar swap.

Comment: You should not grow a vector in a loop. You shouldn't do it in R and absolutely not in C++. Allocate a vector of the maximum length possible and reduce its size after the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I opted to code it in Julia

Logic same just put the curly R braces in:

```
signal = [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]

n_day = zeros(signal)
i = 1
j = 1
for i in 1:length(signal)
if signal[i] == 1
    n_day[i] = 1
    j = 1
    print("i =", i)
while(j<=4)
  # Carry over index position
        n = i + j  # carry over index position
    n_day[n] = 1
    j = j + 1
end
j=1
n=1
end
end
```

for output:

```
julia> print(n_day)
[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
```